# SFSafariViewController takes tint color few seconds after presenting

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

After i present SFSafariViewController for first time its "done" and other buttons are blue for one second, maybe even less and than it becomes my color. Second time i present SFSafariViewController it tint color is mine from start.

```
let safariVc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    safariVc.preferredControlTintColor = UIColor.primaryColor
}

vc.present(safariVc, animated: true)
```